# Object exists but is still undefined in youtube response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube-api

I'm having a little trouble with some Youtube API JS. I have troubleshooted for a while and I have annotated my code with comments so that you understand what the problem is. I know that their are several different things thay might be wrong. Anyway thanks for helping out!

```
   request.execute(function(response) {
      console.log(response.result.items); // Here you get an array of objects.
      var results = response.result;
      console.log(results.items.length);
      var id = results.items.id;
      for (id in results.items) {

      console.log(results.items.id); // And here it is undedfine. When adding video.Id the console says cannot read property videoId of undefined.
      console.log('if you read this the loop works');
  }
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access an `id` property on an array, which doesn't exist (hence, `undefined`).  The main problem is that `for in` in JavaScript is for iterating through object keys, not arrays.  Use a regular `for` loop:

```
request.execute(function (response) {
  var results = response.result;
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    console.log(results[i]);
  }
});
```

If you don't need to support IE8, you can use a `.forEach()`.

(As a side note, read up a bit on `for in` with JavaScript, as your usage is a bit incorrect.)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I think what you are trying to say is that, even the ID object does exist it can't be accessed in a for in loop, since it can only go one sub-level down because it uses object keys.